# задать кол-во видимых объектов в выпадающем списке ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx

Есть код:

```
public ObservableList<String> gymList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Test 1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4");
@FXML
public ChoiceBox gym;

public void initialize() {
    gym.setItems(gymList);

    gym.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            System.out.println(newValue);
            if (newValue == "Test3") {
                lng.setText("45");
                lat.setText("58");
            }
            }
        });
}
```

Как указать в выпадающем меню, скажем, 3 видимых объекта, а остальные будут доступны по скроллу?

Пробовал добавить `gym.setVisibleRow(3);`

IDEA ругается

> Error:(968, 24) java: identifier expected

Answer (score -1):

Решил свою проблему путем смены `ChoiceBox` на `ComboBox`. В `ComboBox` `setVisibleRowCount(3)` работает без проблем.